# How to programmatically view different language keyboard in Android app?

Tags: android, keyboard, native

In my app I have a user language selection option and accordingly user should be able to type in his native language.

For this I need to display the native language keyboard when user click on the language selection list.

I searched and found the multiple answers of using settings -> language & Keyboard also found answers of Long click and choosing keyboard from input method but as the user is totally unaware about the settings and input method.

So I need to programmatically display the native language keyboard from my application only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Android KeyBoard language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715072/change-android-keyboard-language)