# Localization for android EditText

Tags: android, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Android KeyBoard language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715072/change-android-keyboard-language)

Android supports the localization from application, Please find the sample code here

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

My application contains the activity which has one editText. But after changing locale from application, when i click on editText to write, android keyboard launches and it doesn't display any locale changes on keyboard's OK button.

Is there any work around for EditText locale ?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes but didn't get the proper answer

Comment: There's no point in asking twice the same question...

Answer (score 0):

I think that although you can change the locale for your application so it uses different resources, the keyboard will still be using the system locale, chosen by the user in the system settings.