# How to change Android keyboard language for input emails on a Crosswalk webview

Tags: android, webview, keyboard, crosswalk-runtime

We have a 4.2 android app working in different languages. In the greek language, emails are written with the latin alphabet so we need the keyboard  showing up for those fields to be in English, and in any other field, in Greek.

The webapp specifies those email fields as `input type="email"` but the keyboard showing up is in greek, with the @ symbol though.

So, we need to show a different keyboard than the system language on the email field (as in Greece, people don't have emails with greek chars)

I've thought about capturing the click event for those fields in the crosswalk activity and change the keyboard there (with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715072/change-android-keyboard-language)), but I'm not sure if it'd be the correct way of doing it or if it'd work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just discovered this flag which describes your problem: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_FLAG_FORCE_ASCII

`[...] For instance, users of languages using a different script like Arabic, Greek, Hebrew or Russian typically have a keyboard that can't input ASCII characters by default. [...]`

In a native app, you could configure the keyboard specifying an `imeOptions` in the EditText (see http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Action). Not sure if you could plug that in via a Cordova plugin or any other method into your hybrid app.